# how to extract call graph from eclipse call hierarchy?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, abstract-syntax-tree, call-graph

thanks so much for your watching, I'm trying to extract the call graph for a project by using eclipse call hierarchy, and followings are some information.

What I know:

1: We could use call hierarchy function of eclipse to generate the caller and callee for every method in a target project (without compile).

2: The functions are mainly provided by

2.1. org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.callhierarchy.CallHierarchy;

2.2. org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.callhierarchy;

3: We could import the above classes and build our own code.

requirements:

1. The project is not compilable, which means I need to use functions like call hierarchy to build the call graph from the resolved whole project AST trees.
2. I want to build the inner code or command line scripts to extract the call graph for the project by using above classes.
3. If there are some other tools can apply samiliar functions, I'd also be willing to try them.

I've made some try, but I'm still not so sure how to do the generation. Could you give me some help? Thanks so much for that.